# Efficiently reading .txt file for storage in a SQL database using C# and EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been researching a fast and memory-efficient way to store information from a `.txt` file into a SQL database with 35 distributed columns. This text string consists of 136 alphanumeric characters in each line.

One of these files can have up to 5-8 million lines. I need to process and separate them so they can later be queried with various queries.

What I've used is a `string.substring(0, 3)` (yes, I need 35 columns doing this or something similar) as an example of what I want to take of the string and converted it into an attribute of the EF Core entity.

I found that reading the file in batches and using parallelism was optimal, but I'm struggling to improve processing or reduce RAM consumption. The GC doesn't seem to clean it up either. Also, it depends of the hardware specs but right now that's not a problem.

I don't have anything concrete to show at the moment, but if you have any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate them.

EDIT: Here is my last code what I tested.

BatchSizeCounter Class:
This utility class is used to keep track of the number of records in a batch

ProcessFileAsync Method:
This method processes the records in batches using the BatchSizeCounter and inserts each batch into the database.

ProcessBatchAsync Method:
This method saves the records to the database as a Range (Recommended for processing speed)

ParseRecord Method:
This method takes a line (assumed to be a record) and parses it to create an instance of the BAS class. It uses Span to extract substrings from the line based on fixed positions (based on the suggestion of jonathan wood but dont get a better performance (Consuming 14,2 GB of RAM at 4.100.000 while reading 5.475.000 records).

I know that the code is not very well adjusted and I took some recommendations but I fear that it is not well implemented since I have never used Span

Note: At the end, the RAM Consumption was 16,6 GB with

```
public class BatchSizeCounter
{
    private int _count;
    private readonly int _batchSize;

    public BatchSizeCounter(int batchSize)
    {
        _batchSize = batchSize;
    }

    public bool IsBatchComplete => _count >= _batchSize;

    public void Decrement()
    {
        _count++;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _count = 0;
    }
}
```

```
class Process {
        private const int BatchSize = 100_000; // Adjust batch size as needed
        private const int MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 12; // Adjust parallelism level as needed
        public async Task ProcessFileAsync(string filePath)
        {
            using var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            var batchSize = new BatchSizeCounter(BatchSize);
            var records = new List<BAS>();

            string line;
            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                BAS record = ParseRecord(line);

                records.Add(record);
                batchSize.Decrement();

                if (batchSize.IsBatchComplete)
                {
                    // Process the batch in parallel
                    await ProcessBatchAsync(records);
                    records.Clear();
                    batchSize.Reset();
                }
            }

            if (records.Any())
            {
                // Process the remaining records in a final batch
                await ProcessBatchAsync(records);
            }
        }

        private async Task ProcessBatchAsync(IEnumerable<BAS> records)
        {
            await _context.BAS.AddRangeAsync(records);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        // 
        private static BAS ParseRecord(string line)
        {
            var span = line.AsSpan();

            return new BAS
            {
                Prop1 = span.Slice(0, 3).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop2 = span.Slice(3, 3).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop3 = span.Slice(6, 2).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop4 = span.Slice(8, 6).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop5 = span.Slice(14, 1).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop6 = span.Slice(15, 1).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop7 = span.Slice(16, 3).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop8 = span.Slice(19, 3).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop9 = span.Slice(22, 3).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop10 = span.Slice(25, 1).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop11 = span.Slice(26, 1).ToString(), // This property is text
                Prop12 = span.Slice(27, 1).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop13 = span.Slice(28, 6).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop14 = span.Slice(34, 5).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop15 = span.Slice(39, 8).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop16 = span.Slice(47, 6).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop17 = span.Slice(53, 6).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop18 = span.Slice(59, 8).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop19 = span.Slice(67, 1).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop20 = span.Slice(68, 1).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop21 = span.Slice(69, 1).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop22 = span.Slice(70, 1).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop23 = span.Slice(71, 1).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop24 = span.Slice(72, 6).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop25 = span.Slice(78, 2).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop26 = span.Slice(80, 1).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop27 = span.Slice(81, 10).ToString(), // This property is text
                Prop28 = span.Slice(91, 8).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop29 = span.Slice(99, 10).ToString(), // This property is text
                Prop30 = span.Slice(109, 4).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop31 = span.Slice(113, 14).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop32 = span.Slice(127, 3).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop33 = span.Slice(130, 1).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop34 = span.Slice(131, 4).ToString(), // This property is a number
                Prop35 = span.Slice(135, 1).ToString() // This property is a number
            };
        }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to get rid of EF and use something like `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: The best way to pass bulk data to the database would be via either `SqlBulkCopy` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/bulk-copy-operations-in-sql-server or by populating a "table value parameter" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters. The efficiency of parsing text files is a secondary concern.

Comment: Thought I'd remove ef core for this part since I can't just get rid of it entirely and use dapper or something. The problem that I forgot to mention is that I cannot make a bulkcopy for reasons beyond my control.

Comment: If you are stuck using EF Core to issue insert / update statements, improving your file parsing isn't going to help much. If you need to process that much data, and you can't use bulk insert for security reasons. You can still use a TVP without stored procedures. Just `CREATE TYPE [...] AS TABLE (...)` and `GRANT EXECUTE ON type::[...] TO [...]`. Then you can `insert ... select * from @p`.

Comment: SQL Server Integration Server - SSIS handles ETL (Extract Transform Load) loads like this very well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I wish you showed some of your code. If you process a line at a time from the input file then memory shouldn't be an issue. But I can't tell if you're looking for a faster parser or what exactly? If you need a faster parser, then use `AsSpan()` instead of `Substring()`. `AsSpan()` is faster because it doesn't allocate any memory from the heap, and because it doesn't add to the garbage collector's workload.

Comment: I second Flydog57's suggestion to use SSIS. Worked pretty ok when I had to. Now, granted you may not be _able to use it_ due to restrictions set upon you from "above", we can improve each contributing piece but we would really need to see at least something that goes in the direction of a [mcve]. Like replacing `string.Substring` by using `Span` would be a rather easy piece to improve on.

Comment: I will get you some code in the next hours because right now I dont have any at the moment. Maybe that can give you all an idea of the things i have been working. This code is just from c# code and background services (not implemented yet)

Comment: I just added the necessary code.

Comment: For the memory growth issue, I think it will be due to the accumulation of items in `_context.BAS` - you need to clear them out once they've been committed to the database.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Applying your suggestion (if i am correct), the RAM consumption with ```_context.ChangeTracker.Clear();``` was 3 GB RAM but in the end these 3GB were kept occupied until I finished the application. 
This is definitely an improvement that I did not expect to achieve since it has been the best result I have obtained

Comment: Yes, I think `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` probably does what I was suggesting. I haven't used it myself, and its documentation isn't very clear. Is the `BAS` emptied after the call to `ChangeTracker.Clear()`? Alternatively, you might just want to discard the context and start a new one - this comment seems to indicate that would be the "standard" way to do batching: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27670#issuecomment-1072974005

Comment: Somewhere I had read about the unit of work for these cases using IDisposable. I'm using DI so I think that would suit me. I hope for soon to bring results and see if the code can be further improved. Thanks for the suggestions @SimonMᶜKenzie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear();` will help to optimize your RAM consumption but still allocate some RAM.

Unit of Work will work nice if someone need to optimize better your RAM consumption and have a pattern to keep your code and unit test clean.

Answer (score 0):

try using SQL Server's BCP tool with a format file, outlined here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16 .  That way you should be able to bulk load with columns to a table.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to say that I cannot make a bulkcopy for reasons beyond my control but that will work for someone that can use it